# MongoDB watch pipeline

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to listen to the changes with the help of watch pipelines, but there is no output. Even though when I click the button in the front end the values are changing in MongoDB atlas but it doesn't show in Node.Js. There is a perfect connection to the MongoDB from Node.js. You can find the code that I have used below.

```
  const pipeline = [
     { 
         $match : { 
             $and: [
                {serialNumber : "917211212a"},
                {typeDevice: "Light"}
             ]
            }
        },
        {
            $project:{
                _id:0,
                name: 1,
                state: 1,
                startTime:1,
                finishTime:1
            }
        }
          ];


mongoConnect(() => {
const db = getDb();
var collection = db.collection('devices');

const changeStream = collection.watch(pipeline);


changeStream.on('change',function(event) {

console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
}
)}
```

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using? what is the cluster deployment model, is it a standalone or replica set?

Comment: @Mani , i am using MongoDB version 3.1.13, I didn't deploy it yet only working in localhost and pulling data from MongoDB Atlas, i am sorry but not sure about whether it is standalone or replica as i am quite new in MongoDb.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB change stream is available only from `version 3.6` also you should run your mongod as `replica set` and use `wiredtiger` storage engine to avail this feature.

From MongoDB official documentation.

> New in version 3.6.
>
> Change streams allow applications to access real-time data changes
>   without the complexity and risk of tailing the oplog. Applications can
>   use change streams to subscribe to all data changes on a single
>   collection, a database, or an entire deployment, and immediately react
>   to them. Because change streams use the aggregation framework,
>   applications can also filter for specific changes or transform the
>   notifications at will.
>
> Change stream is available for replica sets and sharded clusters that
>   use WiredTiger storage engine and replica set protocol version 1
>   (pv1). Change streams can also be used on deployments which employ
>   MongoDB’s encryption-at-rest feature.

Comment: In Node.js Driver of MongoDb the latest version is 3.1, which I have up to date version. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Its basically what's the version of the MongoDB server.

Comment: I have checked the Atlas MongoDB it has available replica sets and sharded clusters, but it is not still working. Could you provide me with the working example? For example, if some of the fields of "serialNumber" have been changed then i need to detect it straigh away. Are there any option to do this? I am missing something.

Comment: Please Refer this link https://medium.com/@thakkaryash94/mongodb-3-6-change-streams-example-with-node-js-2b9a85652c50